# Can't update Button's text in a Widget

Tags: android, widget, homescreen, remoteview, appwidgetprovider

How do I access items of a homescreen `Widget`, so I can make changes to them like setting a `Button`'s text? In my `AppWidgetProvider`'s `onReceive()` method I'm trying to set the text of a `Button`, which is in my homescreen widget:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(MainActivity.ACTION_CHANGE_BUTTONSTATE))
        {
            String state = intent.getExtras().getString("state");
            Log.d("HomescreenWidget", "received broadcast for button state");

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.id.widgetButton);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetButton, state);
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context,
                    HomescreenWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, views);
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

My Widget's `layout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playButton_Widget"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:text="@string/playButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm receiving the `Broadcast`, but then my `Widget` shows following text: "Problem loading widget".

**EDIT** 
I found following message at the catlog:

```
W/AppWidgetHostView(135): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
W/AppWidgetHostView(135): android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: can't find view: 0x7f0a0004
```

`0x7f0a0004` is my `Widget`'s `Button`. What could be the reason, that it can't be found?

Comment: Sorry just want to reconfirm you want to change some view in your apps from your homescreen widget?

Comment: I got a `Button` that belongs to a homescreen `Widget`'s `layout`. When this button is pressed, I want to change its text label. For this purpose I need a reference to it

Comment: text label in the homescreen widget?

Comment: a `Button`, a button, that's in the homescreen widget. this button has a text label like this:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/_VZJksQ6kepc/TZCBDL7bqnI/AAAAAAAAAC8/w_aNgHvFRIU/s800/layout_weight_1_buttons_fill_screen_width.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution. The whole time I was passing the wrong ID for the Button. `widgetButton` did not exist in the `Widget`'s layout. It was a button from my main `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

To Access your view via appwidget provider you can use this remote views

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetname, newName);
```

or via service :

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
        .getApplicationContext());

    int[] allWidgetIds = intent
        .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
          .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget_layout);

      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update,
          "Random: " + String.valueOf(number));

      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    stopSelf();

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
  }

}
```

and don't forget to add the service to the manifest

```
<service android:name=".UpdateWidgetService"></service>
```

and then in the onUpdate (in your App Widget Provider class)

```
@Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
        UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

    context.startService(intent);
  }
```

I hope this can help :)

Comment: I've tried it via the remoteviews as you said (I edited the question, so you can see what I did). Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

import android.widget.RemoteViews;

//grab the layout, then set the text of the Button called R.id.Counter:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.my_layout);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.Counter, "Set button text here");
```